# [google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1]. GMSx_CCTClearcutUploader crashIfNecessary

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps

With `google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1` on iOS physical device,  I have this console warning message:

```
Runner[15058[/0x1067e8580]()] [lvl=3] 
+[GMSx_CCTClearcutUploader crashIfNecessary] Multiple instances of CCTClearcutUploader were instantiated. 
Multiple uploaders function correctly but have an adverse affect on battery performance due to lock contention.
```

Flutter setup:

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.10.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 097d3313d8 (7 days ago) • 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
Engine • revision a83ed0e5e3
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Same message, physical iPhone, google_maps_flutter ^2.1.1.  Flutter 2.8.1 Dart 2.15.1 (haven't updated yet).  I'm seeing slow performance rendering the map (lots of markers).  By any chance are you also running any firebase packages?

Comment: Yes I use firebase
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.6
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.7

Comment: I'm still getting these errors / warnings, but they don't seem to be having any impact on my app.  I did report it to the google issue tracker last month, and noticed there was some activity recently -- you might want to follow the thread over there:  [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227709813?pli=1)

Comment: same here, it still continues

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105857

Comment: Thanks efesahin, Google seems to be confirming that this is a warning only.